# how to export csv file checkbox value into table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

**school_type col checkbox data export csv file into table. I tried under my code**

**student.rb**

```
# for csv file
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w{id status email temp_registration_date full_name full_name_kana main_registration_date email2 postal_code1 postal_code2 address1 address2 tel_main tel_sub sex school_type school_name school_name_initial department_name faculty_type graduation_month
industry_id industry_most_id occupation_id occupation_most_id desired_work_region_code club_flg school_club_name school_club_type club_name lab_name major_field
research_subject_title research_subject_summary interested_companies personal_summary how_known how_known_other mail_magazine_flg}

  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    all.each do |student|
      csv << [student.id,student.name, student.sex, if (student.school_type == 1)
    大学
 elsif (student.school_type == 2)
    大学院(修士)
 elsif (student.school_type == 3)
    大学院（博士）
 elsif (student.school_type == 4)
    短大
 elsif (student.school_type == 5)
    専門学校
 elsif (student.school_type == 6)
    高専
    end]
  end
end
```

**I have my table**

[**My table data image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oCr9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something more like this:

```
    attributes = %w{id status email...}
    
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      # Build headers
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |student|
        # use a variable to set the school_type string
        school_type_text = if (student.school_type == 1)
          "大学"
        elsif (student.school_type == 2)
          "大学院(修士)"
        elsif (student.school_type == 3)
          "大学院（博士）"
        elsif (student.school_type == 4)
          "短大"
        elsif (student.school_type == 5)
          "専門学校"
        elsif (student.school_type == 6)
          "高専"
        end
        csv << [student.id, student.name, student.sex, school_type_text]
      end
    end
```

I ran that on an `OpenStruct.new({school_type: 2, id: 1, name: 'test'})`
(not in Rails) and the output is:

```
"id,status,email,temp_registration_date,full_name,full_name_kana,main_registration_date,email2,postal_code1,postal_code2,address1,address2,tel_main,tel_sub,sex,school_type,school_name,school_name_initial,department_name,faculty_type,graduation_month,industry_id,industry_most_id,occupation_id,occupation_most_id,desired_work_region_code,club_flg,school_club_name,school_club_type,club_name,lab_name,major_field,research_subject_title,research_subject_summary,interested_companies,personal_summary,how_known,how_known_other,mail_magazine_flg
\n1,test,something,大学院(修士)\n"
```

Comment: No add if condition in variable

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing value each time you could have a hash

```
SCHOOL_TYPE = {1=>'大学', 2=>'大学院(修士)', 3=>'大学院（博士）', 4=>'短大',  5=>'専門学校', 6=>'高専'}
```

And do something like this

```
CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes
    all.each do |student|
      csv << [student.id, student.name, student.sex, SCHOOL_TYPE[student.school_type]]
    end
end
```